# How to pass variables in an Angular selector

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular charComponent that creates pie, and line and other graphs which I want to embed in various places in my app.

I use the selector:

```
<chart></chart>
```

To expose a chart.

What I want to do is embed a variable into the code so I can tell the component what chart I want returning.

So something like this:

```
<chart variable="pie-chart"></chart>
```

Is something like this possible or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is called property binding and is one of the core concepts you should/will be using with Angular.

1. Define the variable, which will be passed to your ChartComponent as

   ```
   export class ChartComponent {

     @Input() public varName: string; // this is typed as string, but you can use any type you want

     constructor() {}
   }
   ```
2. Now you can use

`<chart [varName]="varValue"></chart>`

OR

`<chart varName="varValue"></chart>`

to pass the variable value to the ChartComponent. The difference between the two notations is that with the first one you pass the varValue, which will be evaluated; whereas in the second notation the varName value IS 'varValue'.

And yes, the Angular docs are sometimes quite good. :)

Comment: Ha, this answered my question. I was actually just trying to figure out why [varName]="variable" was not working and then you answered it for me! Thanks a ton!

Comment: And yes, documents are great - my main issue is not knowing the terms to search for such as "property binding".

Comment: That's ok - it is always an uphill battle when one starts with a new framework. It also took me a while before I memorized core concepts and terms in Angular. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this first https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: This got me onto the right path, thank you for taking the time to post.